# Passing extra attributes to join table when populating the form with collection_check_boxes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to add extra attributes to join table when populating form with `collection_check_boxes` in rails or do I have to populate the form in a different manner?

Currently I have Product, Package and PackageItem models. Packages contain many products but can also have multiple instances of each product in a package (eg a package could have 2 turntables in it). In my form I have:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :product_ids, Product.all, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => true } %>
```

and in my packages controller I allow `product_ids => []` in strong params. The join is being successfully created with the 2 foreign keys in the package_items table however there is another column `number` where I wish to store the number of each product in a package. Is it possible to do this using `collection_check_boxes` or do I have to build my form in a different way?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? If yes, could you post your answer?

Comment: Hi Vitor I have added an answer to how I proceeded (it doesn't answer the exact question I asked but was a better solution for me in the end). I hope this gives you enough to continue. If anything is unclear/needs further explaining please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, this is how I solved this issue (using a number input field).

Relevant section of form:

```
<div id="package_products" class="col-xs-8">
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="col-xs-4 field">
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'product[][id]', product.id %>
      <%= label_tag 'product[][name]', product.name %>
      <%= number_field_tag 'product[][quantity]', {}, id: "product_" + product.id.to_s %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And my packages controller code (notice I manually populate the fields as to be able to add the non-join params... not sure if there is a more rails way to do this?). Also not sure about the security of my solution as I have not included `product[:quantity]` in strong params in the private section at the bottom of the controller (can't remember my rational). Theoretically this means that someone could insert malicious code in the db but it's highly unlikely as it's an integer field and it was only editable by admins who would be sabotaging themselves. If you are releasing a consumer app into the wild I would double check the potential repercussions of this:

```
 def create
    @package = Package.new(package_params)
    @package_items = params[:product].delete_if { |product| !product[:quantity].present? || (product[:quantity]).to_i <= 0}
    if @package.save 
      @package_items.each do |x|
        packageitem = PackageItem.create(package_id: @package.id, product_id: x['id'], quantity: x['quantity'])
        packageitem.save!
      end
        respond_to do |format|
           flash.now[:notice] = "Package was successfully created!"
            format.html { redirect_to packages_path }
            format.json { head :no_content }
            format.js
        end
    end
  end



private

    def set_products
      @products = Product.all
    end

    def package_params
      params.require(:package).permit(:name, :price, :package_image, :multiple_day_discount)
    end
```

And model/package_item.rb

```
class PackageItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :package
    belongs_to :product
end
```